# Use (insert and select) temp table in the store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I use below code to create procedure to using temp table

```
Go
create procedure testTempTable
as
    INSERT INTO #resultTbl (code,userName) SELECT code,userName FROM Customer
    select * from #resultTbl
Go
```

When I want to run the procedure with **exec testTempTable** says

> Invalid object name '#resultTbl'.

How can I use temp table in the procedure?

Comment: I feel like thisight be an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). Certainly the above is an over simplification, but as a result it makes the temporary table pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your temp table might not be created, so you can't get result set from `#resultTbl`. you can try to use `SELECT ... INTO` temp table or create a temp table before you use it.

```
create procedure testTempTable
as
BEGIN
    SELECT code,userName 
    INTO #resultTbl
    FROM Customer
    
    SELECT * 
    FROM #resultTbl
    
END
Go
```